# Calculating $\iiint_K \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the following **in cylindrical coordinates**:
$$\iiint_K \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
$K$ is bounded by the plane $z=3$ and by the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

I know that:
$x=r\cos{\theta}$
$y=r\sin{\theta}$
$z=z$

So I get the following:
$$\iiint r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\,d\theta\, dr\,dz$$

The problem I have is finding from where to where I need to integrate.
I tried the following which was wrong:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta \int_0^3\,dz \int_0^z r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\,dr$$

This gave me the following result:
$\frac{24}{5}\sqrt{3}\pi$
Which is wrong according to my coursebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the limits of integration are correct.
Let's recalculate:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta \int_0^3\,dz \int_0^z r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\,dr=2\pi \int_0^3\,dz \int_0^z r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}\,dr=\frac{2}{3}\pi\int_0^3[\sqrt{(r^2+z^2)^3}]_0^z\,dz=$

$=\frac{2(2\sqrt2-1)}{3}\pi\int_0^3z^3\,dz=\frac{(2\sqrt2-1)}{6}\pi[z^4]_0^3=\frac{27(2\sqrt2-1)}{2}\pi$

What the coursebook say such an outcome?

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? I'm really having trouble defining from where to where I have to integrate.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed. Do not look at it.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the effort though!

Comment: That outcome is right! Thanks a lot! I think I made a mistake while taking the square root.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right process, the problem is not worded correctly (The equation for the solid is incorrect). If $x^2+y^2=z^2$ then it's true that $$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\z=\sqrt{r^2} = r$$ If you adjust for this correction your process will be correct.

Comment: What do you mean by adjusting for that correction?